# Error using Phantom.js with Meteor.js: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, phantomjs, node-fibers

When using Phantom.js and the `phantom` NPM package in Meteor.js, I'm getting an error stating that `Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.`

I tried wrapping the `findOne` function with `Meteor.wrapAsync` and Phantom's callback functions with `Meteor.bindEnvironment` but the error persists.

What can we do?

```
var phantom = Meteor.npmRequire('phantom')
phantom.create(Meteor.bindEnvironment( function (ph) {
  ph.createPage(function (page) {
    page.open('http://www.google.com', function (status) {

        console.log('Page Loaded');

        page.evaluate( function () { 
            return document.documentElement.outerHTML; 
        }, function (html) {

            // ERROR OCCURS HERE
            Animals.findOneAsync = Meteor.wrapAsync(Animals.findOne)
            var animals = Animals.findOneAsync({city:'boston'})

        });

        ph.exit();

    });
  });
}) );
```

**Error:**

```
Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.
```